# Complex XSLT transformation with tokenize and distinct-values

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

I'm working on an XSL-Transformation consisting of four steps. I figured out the individual steps, but I am stuck on how to put them together. Here is what I want to do:

**Source XML document:**

```
<application>
    <contactPerson>
        <name>Dominik</name>
        <countryCode>DE,SP</countryCode>
    </contactPerson>
    <contactPerson>
        <name>Andrea</name>
        <countryCode>FR</countryCode>
    </contactPerson>
    <contactPerson>
        <name>Alex</name>
        <countryCode>FR,DE</countryCode>
    </contactPerson>
    <contactPerson>
        <name>Andre</name>
        <countryCode>FR</countryCode>
    </contactPerson>
</application>
```

**Target XML document:**

```
<application>
    <memberState>
        <countryCode>DE</countryCode>
        <contactPerson>
            <name>Dominik</name>
        </contactPerson>
        <contactPerson>
            <name>Dorothea</name>
        </contactPerson>
    </memberState>
    <memberState>
        <countryCode>FR</countryCode>
        <contactPerson>
            <name>Fiona</name>
        </contactPerson>
        <contactPerson>
            <name>Fabian</name>
        </contactPerson>
        <contactPerson>
            <name>Florian<name>
        </contactPerson>
    </memberState>
    <memberState>
        <countryCode>GB</countryCode>
        <contactPerson>
            <name>Gabi</name>
        </contactPerson>
        <contactPerson>
            <name>Gert</name>
        </contactPerson>
    </memberState>
</application>
```

I identified the following steps for the process:

1. Take the *countryCode*-Tags, split the values at the comma and put them in one list
2. Remove double occurances in the list
3. Create one new *countryCode*-node for each value in the list
4. For each new *countryCode*-node, add all people that are contact person for that country

Now I figured out how to do **step 1**:

```
<memberState>
    <countryCodes>
        <xsl:for-each select="/application/contactPerson">
            <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(./countryCode, ',')">
                <countryCode>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </countryCode>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </countryCodes>
</memberState>
```

For **step 2** I can use `distinct-values()`.

For **step 3** + **step 4** I implemented the following solution:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/application/contactPerson/countryCode[not(. = ../preceding-sibling::*/countryCode)]">
    <memberState>
        <countryCode>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </countryCode>
        <xsl:for-each select="/application/contactPerson[countryCode = current()]">
            <contactPerson>
                <name>
                    <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
                </name>
            </contactPerson>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </memberState>
</xsl:for-each>
```

But how can I bring everything together? My idea was to save the output of each step in a variable and work with it in the next step, but I had problems with the fact that variables in XSLT are read-only. Is there a way to somehow connect the single solutions to get the desired result?

Comment: From your description, it seems that you want a stylesheet that performs magic of some sort or another; given a list of people consisting of Dominik, Andrea, Alex, and Andre, it must drop the information about Andrea, Alex, and Andre and add information about Dorothea, Fiona, Fabian, Florian, Gabi, and Gert.  Cool!

Comment: You are right - now that you mention it. I had to make some modifications to the code before I could post it here, and forgot to change the data appropriately as well. Sorry for this - my fault. Luckely, Martin Honnen was able to figure out what I meant :). Thank you for mentioning it - I will be more careful next time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would simply suggest a single step `for-each-group` solution:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="application">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="contactPerson" group-by="tokenize(countryCode, ',')">
      <memberState>
        <countryCode><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/></countryCode>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
      </memberState>
   </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="contactPerson/countryCode"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Of course several transformation steps are possible but with the tools like `for-each-group` that XSLT 2.0 provides I would first look at using these instead of using several transformation steps.

If you want to use `distinct-values` it is of course possible; I would however only store the string values in a variable and operate on that, I don't see why with XSLT 2.0 you would want a temporary tree. So here is a sample using `distinct-values` and a variable to store them to be processed in a second step (and I use a key for efficiency):

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:variable name="countryCodes" select="distinct-values(application/contactPerson/countryCode/tokenize(., ','))"/>

<xsl:variable name="main-input" select="/"/>

<xsl:key name="country" match="contactPerson" use="tokenize(countryCode, ',')"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="application">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:for-each select="$countryCodes">
      <memberState>
        <countryCode><xsl:value-of select="."/></countryCode>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('country', ., $main-input)"/>
      </memberState>
   </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="contactPerson/countryCode"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I think however that my first suggestion is easier given XSLT 2.0 support.

Comment: The `for-each-group` is what I was looking for. I introduced the different steps only because I tried to solve the problem step by step. Since XSLT 2.0 support ist given, the `for-each-group`-solution is much better.Thanks a lot for your answer.